# Type or namespace could not be found (are you missing a using director or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I moved a folder, deleted some an About.cshtml file, and then updated my solution to .net framework to 7.0.

Now, I am getting this error:

[image: Error I am getting on compilation]

But there is no About.cshtml anywhere. I searched the entire solution for it and it is nowhere to be found.

I also searched the solution file and project files for the About.cshtml. But it is nowhere. It does not seem to exist. How can it be finding this error?

Comment: Did you search if somewhere you have a reference to _AboutModel_? Use CTRL+SHIFT+F and search the whole solution

Comment: Clean and rebuild.

Comment: user9938, you hit the nail on the head. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rookie issue.

Delete bin and obj folders. Clean solution. Rebuild.

Solved.